# Cómo desactivar <input> HTML

Tags: javascript, html

necesito su ayuda 
la situación es que al momento de ingresar datos en un "input" sea item_1 o item_2 necesito que en el otro ya no se pueda digitar(a menos que se vacié el otro).

Este es el código:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <br />
  <div class="container">
   <h3 align="center"></h3>
   <br />
   <h4 align="center">Enter Item </h4>
   <br />
   <form method="post" id="insert_form">
    <div class="table-repsonsive">
     <span id="error"></span>
     <table class="table table-bordered" id="item_table">
      <tr>
       <th>Enter Item_1</th>
       <th>Enter Item_2</th>

       <th><button type="button" name="add" class="btn btn-success btn-sm add"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button></th>
      </tr>
     </table>
     <div align="center">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Insert" />
     </div>
    </div>
   </form>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 
 $(document).on('click', '.add', function(){
  var html = '';
  html += '<tr>';
  html += '<td><input type="text" name="item_1[]" class="form-control item_1" /></td>';
  html += '<td><input type="text" name="item_2[]" class="form-control item_2" /></td>';

  html += '<td><button type="button" name="remove" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button></td></tr>';
  $('#item_table').append(html);
 });
 
 $(document).on('click', '.remove', function(){
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
 });
 
 $('#insert_form').on('submit', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var error = '';
  $('.item_1').each(function(){
   var count = 1;
   if($(this).val() == '')
   {
    error += "<p>Enter Item 1 at "+count+" Row</p>";
    return false;
   }
   count = count + 1;
  });
  
  $('.item_2').each(function(){
   var count = 1;
   if($(this).val() == '')
   {
    error += "<p>Enter Item 2 at "+count+" Row</p>";
    return false;
   }
   count = count + 1;
  });
  
  var form_data = $(this).serialize();
  if(error == '')
  {
   $.ajax({
    url:"insert.php",
    method:"POST",
    data:form_data,
    success:function(data)
    {
     if(data == 'ok')
     {
      $('#item_table').find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
      $('#error').html('<div class="alert alert-success">Item Details Saved</div>');
     }
    }
   });
  }
  else
  {
   $('#error').html('<div class="alert alert-danger">'+error+'</div>');
  }
 });
 
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para ello deberías controlar en el evento keyup de cada input que cuando se escriba algo si el valor del input es diferente a vació se bloquee el otro input, una forma sería de la siguiente manera

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
 $(document).on('click', '.add', function(){
  var html = '';
  var table = $('#item_table')[0];
  
  html += `<tr>`;
  html += `<td><input type="text" name="item_1[]" class="form-control item_1" /></td>`;
  html += `<td><input type="text" name="item_2[]" class="form-control item_2" /></td>`;

  html += '<td><button type="button" name="remove" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button></td></tr>';
  $(table).append(html);
 });
 
  $(document).on('keyup', '.item_1',function() {
    var tr = $(this).parents('tr')[0];
    var input2 = tr.getElementsByClassName('item_2');
    
    $(input2).removeAttr('disabled');
    if($(this).val()) {
      $(input2).attr('disabled','disabled');
    }
  });
  $(document).on('keyup', '.item_2',function() {
    var tr = $(this).parents('tr')[0];
    var input1 = tr.getElementsByClassName('item_1');
    
    $(input1).removeAttr('disabled');
    if($(this).val()) {
      $(input1).attr('disabled','disabled');
    }
  });
 
 $(document).on('click', '.remove', function(){
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
 });
 
 $('#insert_form').on('submit', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var error = '';
  $('.item_1').each(function(){
   var count = 1;
   if($(this).val() == '')
   {
    error += "<p>Enter Item 1 at "+count+" Row</p>";
    return false;
   }
   count = count + 1;
  });
  
  $('.item_2').each(function(){
   var count = 1;
   if($(this).val() == '')
   {
    error += "<p>Enter Item 2 at "+count+" Row</p>";
    return false;
   }
   count = count + 1;
  });
  
  var form_data = $(this).serialize();
  if(error == '')
  {
   $.ajax({
    url:"insert.php",
    method:"POST",
    data:form_data,
    success:function(data)
    {
     if(data == 'ok')
     {
      $('#item_table').find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
      $('#error').html('<div class="alert alert-success">Item Details Saved</div>');
     }
    }
   });
  }
  else
  {
   $('#error').html('<div class="alert alert-danger">'+error+'</div>');
  }
 });
 
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <br />
  <div class="container">
   <h3 align="center"></h3>
   <br />
   <h4 align="center">Enter Item </h4>
   <br />
   <form method="post" id="insert_form">
    <div class="table-repsonsive">
     <span id="error"></span>
     <table class="table table-bordered" id="item_table">
      <tr>
       <th>Enter Item_1</th>
       <th>Enter Item_2</th>

       <th><button type="button" name="add" class="btn btn-success btn-sm add"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button></th>
      </tr>
     </table>
     <div align="center">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Insert" />
     </div>
    </div>
   </form>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Como puedes ver se ha intentado que sea de la manera más dinámica posible, obteniendo el tr "parents('tr')[0]" del input y buscando directamente el otro input para así efectuar el bloqueo.

Comment: funciona perfecto,muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

En el siguiente ejemplo, **al introducir algún carácter en uno de los dos input el otro se desactiva. Al borrar los caracteres, ambos inputs vuelven a estar activos.**

#### Solución Vainilla JS

A continuación un código para controlar que sólo se introduce contenido en uno de dos inputs.

```
<input type="text" id="input-1" onkeyup="useInput(this)" />
<input type="text" id="input-2" onkeyup="useInput(this)" />

<script type="text/javascript">

    function enableInput(input_id) {
        document.getElementById(input_id).disabled = false;
    }
    function disableInput(input_id) {
        document.getElementById(input_id).disabled = true;
    }
    function useInput(input_element) {
        var input_id    = input_element.id,
            input_value = input_element.value,
            other_input_id;

        if (input_id == 'input-1') {

            other_input_id = 'input-2';
            if (input_value !== '') {
                disableInput(other_input_id);
            } else {
                enableInput(other_input_id);
            }

            return; // use here to avoid nesting next block in an else
        }

        if (input_id == 'input-2') {

            other_input_id = 'input-1';
            if (input_value !== '') {
                disableInput(other_input_id);
            } else {
                enableInput(other_input_id);
            }

            return; // no neccesary here, but yes if we add more inputs
        }

    }
</script>
```

#### Limitaciones

**El ejemplo controla los eventos de introducción / borrado de contenido mediante la pulsación de teclas.** Si se introdujera o cortará el contenido en uno de los inputs sin usar el teclado (copia y pega mediante el uso de menús por ejemplo), el JS no se ejecutaría, siendo para el caso necesario ampliar el código para controlar otros eventos.